# How do I create VBA Macros for MS Word using the .find property that can use variables?

Tags: vba, ms-word

Just as one example, I have a paragraph that contains the string "50 million dollars".  I would like it to say "$50 million" instead, using the dollar sign instead of spelling out "dollars".  Simply replacing that single instance is trivial.  But say I want to replace all instances of the form "N million dollars" where N is a number between 1 and 1,000.  How do I do that?

It's easy enough to find all instances of "N million dollars" by using something like

```
With Selection.Find
.Text = "[1-1000] million dollars"
.ClearFormatting
.Replacement.Text = "$[1-1000] million"
.Replacement.ClearFormatting
.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Forward:=True
End With
```

The problem is with the replacement text.  We need to somehow store the numeric value that precedes "million dollars", otherwise, as written, it will replace it with the string "$[1-1000] million".  If the original string is "75 million dollars", I want to replace it with "$75 million".  What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

With [wildcard searching](https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-US/article/Find-and-replace-text-and-other-data-in-a-Word-document-c6728c16-469e-43cd-afe4-7708c6c779b7).  You don't even need VBA — in the Find and Replace dialog box, check "Use Wildcards" (hit "More" if you don't see that).  Enter the search text

```
$([0-9]{1,}) million
```

and the replacement text

```
\1 million dollars
```

and hit Replace All.

(Or, for the other way around, search for `([0-9]{1,}) million dollars` and replace with `$\1 million`.)

To do this with VBA, set `Selection.Find.MatchWildcards=True`, `.Text` to the search expression above, and `.Replacement.Text` to the replacement text above.

**Explanation**: In a wildcard search expression, `()` surround portions of the text to be saved.  The first such can then be referred to as `\1`, the second as `\2`, and so on.  `[0-9]` is any digit, and `[0-9]{1,}` is any number of digits.

Note that wildcards are case-sensitive and whitespace-sensitive.

- If you have to handle uppercase as well, replace any letter in the Find expression above with its lower- and upper-case forms in square brackets.  E.g., `[Mm]illion [Dd]ollars` will match "million dollars", "Million dollars", and so forth.
- If you have nonbreaking spaces in your document, or if you might have multiple spaces or tabs between words (e.g., `million   dollars` vs. `million dollars`, replace each space in the Find expression above with `[ ^s^t]{1,}`.  That will handle any number of spaces, NBSPs, or tabs.

Comment: Thank you very much!  That seems to work perfectly.  I had never seen anything about using \1 or parentheses being able to store values.

Comment: @BIGSCORES glad to hear it, and welcome to the site!  Check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) for more about what to expect.  Would you please upvote (the upward-pointing triangle) if you found this answer helpful, and hit the checkmark to accept the answer if it answered your question to your satisfaction?  Your votes and accepted answers will help future readers evaluate the information and find solutions to their own problems more easily.  Thanks!